# CSS a:active override similar to iPhone TouchUpInside

Tags: css, iphone, user-interface, user-experience

I'm working on a site at the moment and have ventured into CSS Sprites for the first time. On the a:active state i'm shifting the background-position as needed which is working great. However if i click the link and move my mouse off the link whilst still mid-click. The effect stays on the button, even after i release the click!

Is there a CSS rule similar to the iPhone action "TouchUpInside" so its only affected if the user releases the click while still in the link area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying jQuery .mouseout() to those links.

```
$(".myLinks").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css('background-position','0 0'); // original position of your sprite
});
```

Dragging out of the link in mid-click (while the mouse is "down") is not something CSS is capable of handling. CSS would require an additional pseudo class like "a:unactive" for the same effect to happen.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using :hover and want a "third" button state. If so, I can appreciate trying to code for every scenario, but you're really trying to pick fly !@#$ out of pepper... good for you -- I've done it too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but looking at my site's menu the `a:active` setting keeps it enable when you are on that page if you want it to change when someone hovers over it use `a:hover`

try something like this

```
ul.cssmenu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background:url(images/bg%27s/menu.png);
    }

/*
*   Normal Links
*/
ul.cssmenu li.home a {
    background-position: 0 -3px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.photos a {
    background-position: -150px -3px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.racing a {
    background-position: -300px -3px;
    }
    ul.cssmenu li.blog a {
    background-position: -450px -3px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.forum a {
    background-position: -600px -3px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.contact a {
    background-position: -750px -3px;
    }

/*
*   Hover Links
*/
ul.cssmenu li.home a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -54px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.photos a:hover {
    background-position: -150px -54px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.racing a:hover {
    background-position: -300px -54px;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.blog a:hover {
    background-position: -450px -54px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.forum a:hover {
    background-position: -600px -54px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.contact a:hover {
    background-position: -750px -54px;
    }

/*
*   Clicked Links
*/
ul.cssmenu li.home a:active {
    background-position: 0 -54px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.photos a:active {
    background-position: -150px -54px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.racing a:active {
    background-position: -300px -54px;
    }
ul.cssmenu li.blog a:active {
    background-position: -450px -54px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.forum a:active {
    background-position: -600px -54px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.contact a:active {
    background-position: -750px -54px;
    }

/*
*   Selected/Active Links
*/
ul.cssmenu li.home a.selected {
    background-position: 0 -108px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.photos a.selected {
    background-position: -150px -108px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.racing a.selected {
    background-position: -300px -108px;
    }
    ul.cssmenu li.blog a.selected {
    background-position: -450px -108px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.forum a.selected {
    background-position: -600px -108px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.contact a.selected {
    background-position: -750px -108px;
    }
```

Comment: @benhowdle89 can you post some code of the problem so i can compare

Comment: Just your usual ul > li > a...thats why i'm a bit concerned. Nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: should work are you using one image for the menu and what browser are you testing it on

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using `.myButton:hover` rather than active. As when you mouse off and release the button, the hover state will no longer be applied :)

Comment: I think people are mistunderstanding my slightly, i have a separate :hover effect applied but i'm on about when the user actually clicks down on the button and then moves the mouse away mid-click. Ie cancelling the click. The :active state is still being applied!?